# Ionic - Force caching of images in browser cache

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cache-control

For performance reasons it is very important that some images get cached in my app's browser cache. Just storing them in the file system is not enough, as this is too slow.

Those images are unfortunately fetched from a remote source with `Cache-control` response headers I do not control, and not favorable to my purpose.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to tell the browser to force the caching of those images, and ideally control the expiration of the images ?
2. Is there a way to override the cache-control headers ? I read it's not possible with javascript, but maybe there is a trick in the ionic framework ?

The app is written in ionic and built for android only, so in theory I should be able to control the browser settings.